# ImportError: cannot import name x (no circular dependency)

Tags: python, file, import

Coming across the above error when trying to call a function from another python file.

The main file is:

```
import glob
import os
from . import fileread2

dat = filereader()

print(dat)
```

when running this file it returns the error:

'''
ImportError: cannot import name 'fileread2' from 'thonny.plugins.cpython' (/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thonny/plugins/cpython/**init**.py)
'''

The file 'fileread2' is:

```
#fileread2.py
import glob
import os
import csv

def filereader():
    folder_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop/RG new")
    comlist = []
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.CSV')):
        file = open(filename, 'r')
        lines_list = []
        for line in file:
            newline = line.split(',')
            element_list = []
            for element in newline:
                newelement = element.strip()
                element_list.append(newelement)
            lines_list.append(element_list)
        comlist.append(lines_list)
    
    return comlist
```

I've also tried just 'import fileread2' but that returns the error 'no module named fileread2'

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The only function shown is called `filereader` not `fileread2`. Is `fileread2` the name of the module?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a global function/variable from another file in the same directory, you can import it explicitly:

```
from .fileread2 import filereader

dat = filereader()

print(dat)
```

You could also keep the same import statement and change the way you refer to the function:

```
from . import fileread2

dat = fileread2.filereader()

print(dat)
```

Comment: thanks! I realised my problem was that the file I was wanting to import was sitting in a different folder in my mac to the current file which was causing the issue.